# Как всем div c одним id удалить определенный class?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Вопрос в названии.
Есть список label-ов, делаю так, но удаляет лишь в одном div.

```js
$("#chat-box").removeClass("view-chat-box");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class='view-chat-box' id='chat-box'>list 1</label>
<label class='view-chat-box' id='chat-box'>list 2</label> 
<label class='view-chat-box' id='chat-box'>list 3</label>
```

Есть такой вариант, но здесь ко всем div на странице. Не подходит.

```
$('div').removeClass('view-chat-box');
```

Можно ли обойтись без циклов и как то применить этот код ко всем div-ам?

Comment: не использовать один id на несколько дивов, а сразу выбирать по классу

Comment: А ничего, что id может быть только один на странице?!

Comment: у вас в коде нет ни одного дива

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну так то ID должен быть уникальным , ну а вообще вот так:

```js
$(".view-chat-box").removeClass("view-chat-box");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class='view-chat-box' id='chat-box'>list 1</label>
<label class='view-chat-box' id='chat-box'>list 2</label> 
<label class='view-chat-box' id='chat-box'>list 3</label>
```

Comment: Вот как, спасибо. Не знал что по id так не работает.

Comment: @АльбертУшаков, по id работает, просто jQuery в последних версиях научился брать только первое вхождение, как и требуется.

Comment: @Grundy Извините, а Вы случаем не знайте ли как удалять определенный класс, если их в label несколько и ставить за поиск уникальный класс. То есть class=''view-1 view-chat-box", class=''view-2 view-chat-box" ... удалять нужно "view-chat-box"?

Comment: @АльбертУшаков, чем не подходит принятый ответ? `.removeClass("view-chat-box")` удалит только класс "view-chat-box"

Comment: @Grundy Понимайте, у меня есть группы этих div, к примеру "view-1" может быть несколько и нужно удалить именно в этой группе class "view-chat-box" а стальные не трогать. Делаю так: $('view-1').removeClass("view-chat-box"); Не срабатывает.

Comment: @АльбертУшаков, Это все потому, что в селекторе перед классом надо `.` ставить

Comment: @Grundy Вот блин! Не внимателен... спасибо:)

Answer (score 3):

```
Id на странице может быть только один, потому так функция не будет работать
```

```js
$("#chat-box").removeClass("view-chat-box");
$("#chat-box-1").removeClass("view-chat-box");
$("#chat-box-2").removeClass("view-chat-box");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class='view-chat-box' id='chat-box'>list 1</label>
<label class='view-chat-box' id='chat-box-1'>list 2</label> 
<label class='view-chat-box' id='chat-box-2'>list 3</label>
```

разве, что так

```css
$(".view-chat-box").removeClass("view-chat-box");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class='view-chat-box' id='chat-box'>list 1</label>
<label class='view-chat-box' id='chat-box-1'>list 2</label> 
<label class='view-chat-box' id='chat-box-2'>list 3</label>
```

или так

Comment: или чтобы не для каждого  id: `$("[id*='chat-box-']").removeClass("view-chat-box");`

Comment: через for() цикл нужно прогонять. но так быстрее согласен)

Answer (score 0):

Удаляйте класс у тега `label`

```js
$("label").removeClass("view-chat-box");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class='view-chat-box' id='chat-box'>list 1</label>
<label class='view-chat-box' id='chat-box'>list 2</label> 
<label class='view-chat-box' id='chat-box'>list 3</label>
```